# My pager disappears when I use hook_views_pre_execute

Tags: views, 6, paging

I need to modify a query of one view. So, I use the [`hook_views_pre_execute`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7).
The query is modified but the pager disappears.
My question is why? Do I need to add more lines to hook to use to display the pager?

Code:

```
function view_format_render_views_pre_execute(&$view) {

    if ($view->name == 'view_probe' && $view->display['block_1']->display_title =='List of categories') {
        $tid = $view->args[0];
        $tids = array_keys(taxonomy_get_children($tid));
        $tids=implode(', ',$tids);

         $search = "node_data_field_formatos_colecc.field_formatos_colecc_value = %d";
            $search_new = "node_data_field_formatos_colecc.field_formatos_colecc_value IN ( ".$tids." )";   

            $query = &$view->build_info['query'];
            $query = str_ireplace($search, $search_new, $query);    

            $view->build_info['query'] = $query;

        if (isset($tid) && isset($arguments)) {

                $query = str_ireplace($search_new, '', $query); 
                $view->build_info['query'] = $query;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if query exec is too long (for pagination views must return total count of rows at all pages and correspond it to rows per page ) pagination not returned by views.

nid of nodes returns from one table in database and this queries is very simple & fast

another fields (cck, ubercart, stock) returned from another db tables and it can be too long. for this views just returns first page to prevent timeout